# Sharrre - Pinterest button not working

Tags: javascript, social-networking, pinterest, share-button

I'm using the "sharrre" plugin to add social buttons on one of my websites.

The code is working well for facebook, twitter, and google+.
Pinterest and Linkedin buttons are not showing at all. Any ideas?

```
$('#twitter').sharrre({
  share: { twitter: true },
  url: 'voxita.com',
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><span></span>Tweet</div></a>',
  buttons: { twitter: {via: 'romaeventi'}},
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('twitter');
  }
});

$('#facebook').sharrre({
  share: { facebook: true },
  url: 'voxita.com',
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><span></span>Like</div></a>',
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('facebook');
  }
});

$('#google').sharrre({
  share: { googlePlus: true },
  url: 'voxita.com',
  template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><span></span>+1</div></a>',
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  urlCurl: '',
  buttons: { googlePlus: {size: 'tall', annotation:'bubble'}},
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('googlePlus');
  }
});
$('#pinterest').sharrre({
share: { pinterest: true },
template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><span></span>Pins</div></a>',
enableHover: false,
enableTracking: true,
buttons: { description: '<?php echo the_title(); ?>'},
urlCurl: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/sharrre/sharrre.php'; ?>',
click: function(api, options){
   api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('pinterest');
  }
});
```

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem with Pinterest button. Did you get any update why this is not working?

Comment: I'm also having trouble using Sharrre with Pinterest. Have you solved it by any chance?